# How can I get multiple virtual machines to communicate on the same network using VirtualBox and Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am working to complete a cybersecurity lab (the lab is developed by SEEDLab out of Syracuse University) that simulates a local DNS attack. I am supposed to create three virtual machines in order to conduct safe tests: server_VM, user_VM, and attacker_VM. I am using VirtualBox running Ubuntu 16.04.

I have created the VMs and now I need to run them at the same time, switching back and forth between them simultaneously in order to enter commands into the Ubuntu terminal. When I try to run them at the same time, I keep getting the following message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine User.

Locking of attached media failed. A possible reason is that one of the media is attached to a running VM.

Result Code: VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80BB0007)

Component: SessionMachine

Interface: IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
How do I go about getting the VMs to run simultaneously so that I can communicate with each one by way of command line?
```

I am just trying to get the virtual machines up and running and would be satisfied if I could just get that working at this point. Many thanks.

Other information:

I am using the default network mode (NAT) for each of the VMs.
Here are links to the specific lab site [local DNS lab description](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Networking/DNS_Local/), and also to the pdf which gives the lab instructions [local DNS lab instructions](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Networking/DNS_Local/DNS_Local.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Your error messages are caused by the VM’s using the same media.
This can be because you used the same virtual hard disk image for the VM’s and that won’t work. Each VM needs its own virtual hard disk.
The other possibility is that the install media (ISO file) for Ubuntu is linked to all 3 VM’s while they are running. This ISO is only needed for the base install, so after you are done with installing the first VM you can disconnect the ISO and use it for the 2nd VM.

As for the network part: VM’s setup as NAT are placed in a virtual network using a 10.0.0.x ip-range. Virtualbox will setup dhcp for that subnet and will make sure DNS and such are forwarded to the regular DNS. It does this on basis of the network config of the host system so that needs the setup correctly.
As an alternative you can also setup a host-only network between the VM’s. In which case the VM’s run in an isolated network which is only visible to the VM’s and the host.
In any case consult the excellent Virtualbox manual. It has an extensive section on networking including the (command line only) commands that allow far more possibilities than the GUI configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Vagrant you can use the following `Vagrantfile` which will provision 3 boxes (Ubuntu 16.04).

```
$ cat Vagrantfile
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


##############
### References
# - https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html
# - https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/tips.html
# - https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html
##############

#unless Vagrant.has_plugin?("HostManager")
#  raise 'HostManager plugin not installed!'
#end

image = "ubuntu/xenial64"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  vboxName1 = "box-101"
  hostname1 = "box1"
  config.vm.define "#{vboxName1}" do |box|
    box.vm.box = "#{image}"
    #box.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.101"
    box.vm.network :public_network, use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true
    box.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 512]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "#{hostname1}"]
    end
  end

  vboxName2 = "box-102"
  hostname2 = "box2"
  config.vm.define "#{vboxName2}" do |box|
    box.vm.box = "#{image}"
    #box.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.103"
    box.vm.network :public_network, use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true
    box.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 512]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "#{hostname2}"]
    end
  end

  vboxName3 = "box-103"
  hostname3 = "box3"
  config.vm.define "#{vboxName3}" do |box|
    box.vm.box = "#{image}"
    #box.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.103"
    box.vm.network :public_network, use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true
    box.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 512]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "#{hostname3}"]
    end
  end
end
```

To use it:

```
# launches all VMs
$ vagrant up

# ssh into box-101
$ vagrant ssh box-101
```

For more on using `vagrant` consult the usage:

```
$ vagrant
```

Comment: +1 for Vagrant, really the best way to setup and run several machines on a virtual network.